# What happens when I pass an XsltParameter to an XSLT but don't define it in the XSLT?

Tags: c#, xslt

I'm looking for what happens when you do the following:

1. Create an `XslCompiledTransform`
2. Create an `XsltArgumentList`
3. Add a parameter to the list using `xslArg.AddParam("name", "", "value")`
4. Load an XSLT that does not define `<xsl:param name="name" />`

Does this cause an error, or does the .NET XSLT engine handle this gracefully?

Comment: Just for clarification: yes, I am going to test this, but I couldn't find the answer online so I created a question for it.

Comment: @Selman22 dude, read the comment I left.  I am going to try this.  I just asked the question so other people could find it.

Comment: @keshlam can you provide a reason/example why and include it as an answer?

Comment: @keshlam like I said in a comment to your question - this is specifically for .NET's XSLT engine.  I appreciate the perspective, but I don't think that adds much to the question

Comment: Good enough. Still getting a handle on where SO draws the line.

Comment: np :)  SO prefers to use tags (the little blue boxes below the question) rather than saying "C# .NET" in the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives no problem at runtime, the provided arguments in the [XsltArgumentList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are ignored by the [Transfrorm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the XslCompileTransform class. Notice that loading the stylesheet will never be the problem because the parameter binding doesn't need to be provide for that method.

```
var xct = new XslCompiledTransform();
 var  xslArg = new  XsltArgumentList();
 xslArg.AddParam("name", "", "foobaz");

 xct.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(
   @"<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">
        <xsl:template match=""/"">
            result:<xsl:value-of select=""."" />+
        </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>")));

  var ms = new MemoryStream();
  xct.Transform(
    XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(@"<root>bar</root>")),
    xslArg,
    ms);

  var s = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

  s.Dump();
```

**produced output:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     result:bar+
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  You beat me to testing it (went to lunch :P )